# IDLE not integrated in desktop

Tags: python, installation, python-idle

Just installed Python 2.7.3 on a Windows7 machine.

How do I get .py files to be associated with python (they are with notepad ATM) and how do I get the context menu shortcut for "edit in IDLE"? Somehow I didn't get that on this particular computer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try making a .py file and then try to open it, and a window should appear asking you what to open it with, and then select idle in your program files.

Comment: I get pythonw.exe as an option but when I run it, even with a a= raw_input( "yes?" ) command it doesn't seem to be running. At least that gets me the icon on the file.

Comment: Seems to be fixed now. I uninstalled and reinstalled it. Followed Nick's suggestion (since python.exe now showed up as an option) and made it default. IDLE now shows up on the context menu.